# Adding Lighting effect in JavaFX8 from CSS

Tags: css, javafx, effects, lighting

I am trying to add the lighting effect to a button through the CSS file, I have searched and could only find ways to do it through JavaFx code. Can anyone help?`

```
 .button.CommitButtonBig {
      -fx-background-color:  #24BE58;
      -fx-text-fill: white;
      -fx-background-radius: 5px; 

}

.button.CommitButtonBig:hover{
     -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#39e600, #39e600);
}   

.button.CommitButtonBig:focused{
     -fx-effect: lighting;
  }   `
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add a lighting effect via CSS in JavaFX 8.  The [`-fx-effect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect) attribute only supports values for DropShadow and InnerShadow effects.  Lighting effects must be added in code.